# Django query set to display particular field on webpage

Tags: django, rest, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am trying to display the variants(field) that are related to the model RecordVariant on my webpage i have queryset on my view default how can i change my queryset or get queryset method to display variants that are related to particular record.

```
class RecordVariant(models.Model):
    variants = models.ForeignKey(Variant_model, related_name = 'records', on_delete = 
                                models.CASCADE)

class Variant(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 23, blank=True, null=True)
    

class RecordVariantListAPIView(RecordMixin, ListAPIView):
    lookup_url_kwarg = 'record_id'
    serializer_class = RecordVariantSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    pagination_class = StandardResultsSetPagination
    filter_backends = (filters.OrderingFilter,)
    queryset = RecordVariant.objects.all()
    ordering = 'variants'
    ordering_param = 'ordering'
    ordering_fields = (
    'variants',
)

    def get_total_queryset(self):
        queryset = (
            super()
            .get_queryset()
           .filter(record=self.record)
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

in foreignkey relations the child should be the one with foreginkey field.
meaning your Variant model class should have this field

```
class Variant(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 23, blank=True, null=True)
    records = models.ForeignKey(RecordVariant, related_name = 'records', 
              on_delete = models.CASCADE)


class RecordVariant(models.Model):
    pass
```

and for the serializers

```
class Variant(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Variant
        fields = "['name']"


class RecordVariant(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    records = VariantSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = RecordVariant
        fields = '__all__'
```

the view

```
class RecordVariantListAPIView(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = RecordVariantSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    queryset = RecordVariant.objects.all()
```